# Merging data from SPSS version 0 to SPSS version 19

Tags: merge, spss

I'm new to SPSS, so this may be an easy question to answer. I have data in SPSS version 0 (I know that version is ancient, but it's the one my professor uses). He wants me to merge it with other data in SPSS version 19. In other words, he wants all the data in version 19. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Version 0? Is it on a punch card???

Comment: @AndyW essentially, yes. It's on a computer from the 80's that doesn't have a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe that there really was a version 0 that anyone could have data from.  That would date from the 1960's  Perhaps the data are from the first PC product, SPSS/PC or SPSS/PC+, which date from around 1984 - 1993.  If so, the file extension would be .sys.  Such files can be read in current versions by choosing that file type in File > Open > Data.